# Hadoop: Need to remove a single data directory from all data nodes

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I need to reclaim disk space from all my Hadoop HDFS datanodes.  They are each configured like this:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>/d01,/d02,/d03</value>
</property>
```

How should I go about safely removing the /d03 filesystem from all nodes and rebalancing them?  I've experimented with decommissioning a node, removing the directory, and recommissioning, but it is very slow and am wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: I solved it myself through just getting a better (or, basic) understanding of how Hadoop works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix is actually very simple, and follows from knowledge of what HDFS is for.  The filesystem is a distributed collection of replicated blocks that is failure tolerant.  Therefore, simply removing the extra directories from a datanode in the cluster and restarting is sufficient to cause re-synchronisation and replication of the blocks to occur.

Monitor the NameNode log and the WebUI "Number of Under-Replicated Blocks" to discern when the process is complete.

Repeat for individually for all nodes in the cluster.

Several caveats:

Ensure that

- there are no under-replicated blocks, by checking:
  `http://<name-node>:50070`,
- there is adequate disk space across the other filesystems,
- the replication level is set to at least 2 to ensure that the cluster can tolerate the loss of blocks.  Ideally, this should be three or higher for safety.

Comment: Note: We are using Cloudera and the Cloudera Manager proposed to  restart the whole cluster after changing the config for only one host. You do not need to restart the whole cluster. Just restart HDFS on the changed node.